# stored procedure cursor mysql 5.1

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Below cursor declaration works with 5.0 but not with 5.1.

DECLARE CUR_GBLVAR CURSOR FOR SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;

Comment: That's the most brief sproc I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in MySQL 5.1 as follows:

```
DECLARE CUR_GBLVAR CURSOR FOR 
SELECT VARIABLE_NAME, VARIABLE_VALUE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_VARIABLES
ORDER BY VARIABLE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply.
I already got it from here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49758